# Pandas Multicolumn Evaluation to Generate New Column

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I am trying to create a new column in an existing DataFrame based on evaluating whether values ever exist in two columns.

Assume the following is part of a medium-sized dataset (30 million data points):

```
DATE      |ID    |3_DAY_FUTURE
2016-12-14|Bob123|2016-12-17
2016-12-15|Bob123|2016-12-18
2016-12-16|Bob123|2016-12-19
2016-12-17|Bob123|2016-12-20
2016-12-18|Bob123|2016-12-21
2016-12-19|Bob123|2016-12-22
2016-12-20|Bob123|2016-12-23
2017-01-14|Jim123|2017-01-17
2017-01-15|Jim123|2017-01-18
2017-01-16|Jim123|2017-01-19
2017-01-17|Jim123|2017-01-20
2017-01-18|Jim123|2017-01-21
2017-01-19|Jim123|2017-01-22
2017-01-20|Jim123|2017-01-23
```

I am looking to create a column that evaluates whether each ID (Bob and Jim in this example) has a date value that matches 3 days in the future. For example, Bob123 was present on 2016-12-14 and 2016-12-17 since both DATEs are associated with him. The first row would add a new column that says Yes or something like that. Here is an example of the output I am hoping for with a new 3_DAY_STATUS columns:

```
DATE      |ID    |3_DAY_FUTURE|3_DAY_STATUS
2016-12-14|Bob123|2016-12-17|YES
2016-12-15|Bob123|2016-12-18|YES
2016-12-16|Bob123|2016-12-19|YES
2016-12-17|Bob123|2016-12-20|YES
2016-12-18|Bob123|2016-12-21|NO
2016-12-19|Bob123|2016-12-22|No
2016-12-20|Bob123|2016-12-23|NO
2017-01-14|Jim123|2017-01-17|YES
2017-01-15|Jim123|2017-01-18|YES
2017-01-16|Jim123|2017-01-19|YES
2017-01-17|Jim123|2017-01-20|YES
2017-01-18|Jim123|2017-01-21|NO
2017-01-19|Jim123|2017-01-22|NO
2017-01-20|Jim123|2017-01-23|NO
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create mask by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `ID` with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then add new values by [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df['3_DAY_FUTURE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['3_DAY_FUTURE'])

mask = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['3_DAY_FUTURE'].isin(df.DATE)).values
print (mask)
[ True  True  True  True False False False  True  True  True  True False

df['3_DAY_STATUS'] = np.where(mask, 'YES', 'NO')
print (df)
         DATE      ID 3_DAY_FUTURE 3_DAY_STATUS
0  2016-12-14  Bob123   2016-12-17          YES
1  2016-12-15  Bob123   2016-12-18          YES
2  2016-12-16  Bob123   2016-12-19          YES
3  2016-12-17  Bob123   2016-12-20          YES
4  2016-12-18  Bob123   2016-12-21           NO
5  2016-12-19  Bob123   2016-12-22           NO
6  2016-12-20  Bob123   2016-12-23           NO
7  2017-01-14  Jim123   2017-01-17          YES
8  2017-01-15  Jim123   2017-01-18          YES
9  2017-01-16  Jim123   2017-01-19          YES
10 2017-01-17  Jim123   2017-01-20          YES
11 2017-01-18  Jim123   2017-01-21           NO
12 2017-01-19  Jim123   2017-01-22           NO
13 2017-01-20  Jim123   2017-01-23           NO
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Works on smaller datasets just fine, but really taking hours on the full dataset since only working on one processor. This line in particular: mask = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['3_DAY_FUTURE'].isin(df.DATE)).values

Comment: Yes, it is a bit problematic with performance. What about second answer?

Comment: the second answer does not seem to take into account the segmentation or grouping by ID. seems to just look for an offset regardless of whether the ID is still the same

Answer (score 1):

use `shift(-3)` and `np.where`

```
df['3_DAY_STATUS'] = np.where(df.DATE.shift(-3) == df['3_DAY_FUTURE'], 'YES', 'NO')
print(df)

         DATE      ID 3_DAY_FUTURE 3_DAY_STATUS
0  2016-12-14  Bob123   2016-12-17          YES
1  2016-12-15  Bob123   2016-12-18          YES
2  2016-12-16  Bob123   2016-12-19          YES
3  2016-12-17  Bob123   2016-12-20          YES
4  2016-12-18  Bob123   2016-12-21           NO
5  2016-12-19  Bob123   2016-12-22           NO
6  2016-12-20  Bob123   2016-12-23           NO
7  2017-01-14  Jim123   2017-01-17          YES
8  2017-01-15  Jim123   2017-01-18          YES
9  2017-01-16  Jim123   2017-01-19          YES
10 2017-01-17  Jim123   2017-01-20          YES
11 2017-01-18  Jim123   2017-01-21           NO
12 2017-01-19  Jim123   2017-01-22           NO
13 2017-01-20  Jim123   2017-01-23           NO
```

---

Comment: thanks. i tried your snippet but it doesn't seem to take into account different IDs